# Why TypeScript do not emit a error when use as type?

Tags: typescript, enums

[image]

I expect an error hint when assign 1000 to a Gender Type variable(foo),
as TSC already know the candidates in enum Gender.

below is an ideal behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It only checks if the value is of type 'number' or if you use the Enum it will check if the property exists.

```
let foo: Gender = 'female' or let foo: Gender = Gender.Orange
```

would throw an error for example.

What you should be (always) doing is to use the enum:

```
let foo: Gender = Gender.Female;
```

That way you're safe not to use any Properties that are not present in the enum.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html is also a nice read.

Comment: but the spec says "all that you need to know is that with union enums, the type system is able to leverage the fact that it knows the exact set of values that exist in the enum itself."

Comment: @lynnic The example given is also using the enum members.
If you compare to numbers, typescript will still compile without errors. 
Use the enum so that you can catch mistakes easily.